# Deprecated Methods in C# Mongo Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In the latest version of the C# driver 10gen seems to have shifted to a more typed version of their .find() method. It seems that MongoCollection.Find(IMongoQuery) is deprecated, replaced with MongoCollection.FindAs(Type, IMongoQuery). This is fine (although I don't see the deprecation mentioned anywhere in the documentation); however, MongoCursor no longer contains the .ToList() method. Attempting to work around these missing methods I tried to use MongoCursor.IEnumerableGetEnumerator(), but my IDE complains that this is not a valid method.

To simplify my question below is the code segment of what I was doing, how is this accomplished with the new driver?

```
var queryResult = collection.Find(Query.And(largeQueryList[i])).ToList();
try { result = queryResult.Sum(w => w[valueField].ToDouble()); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure when you last updated the driver, as it doesn't look like that method has been there in quite a while for the `MongoCollection` class. It is present on the generic `MongoCollection<type>` class. The driver needs to know what type to deserialize into, so you'll need to indicate the document type. That could be through a generic BsonDocument:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument>
```

Or, if you have a specific type, you can substitute it there.

If you don't want to use the generic version, you'll need to use `FindAs` or one of the equivalent methods to indicate the `Type`.

Once you do that, you'll see that `ToList` should be available.